# JMeter If-Loop controller

Tags: jmeter

My Test Plan looks something like this:

```
Test Plan
  -> Thread Group
      -> Sampler 1
      -> If condn()
      -> Sampler 2
      -> Loop controller
      -> Sampler 3
```

I want the Loop controller to be triggered after the Sampler 2 is executed.

Now, this works perfectly for me when I try it on a Dummy application. But in the actual app, the control exits after Sampler 2.

I have looked into any possible re-directions but still haven't found a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works.

Check jmeter.log for any error (or activate Log Viewer) and also show Loop Controller GUI Content.